# Google Maps version tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

I spend most of my time answering Google Maps questions, but don't quite get the point of having three tags for them:

- [google-maps](/questions/tagged/google-maps)
- [google-maps-api-3](/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-3)
- [google-maps-api-2](/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-2)

Why should someone choose the [google-maps-api-3](/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-3) tag instead of [google-maps](/questions/tagged/google-maps)?

In other words, why do the -api-3 and -api-2 tags even exist?

Comment: Personally, though I don't know much about the Google Maps API, I would think that if there's something that can be done differently in version 3 than it is in version 2, and that person explicitly wants to use the version 3 method, they would tag it with both `google-maps` and `google-maps-api-3`.

Comment: There are massive differences between syntax and capability of versions 2 and 3 and it's important to know what you're dealing with before answering.