# Please merge "google-maps-api-3" into "google-maps"

Tags: support, status-declined, retag-request

There are three main tags covering Google Maps' JavaScript API:

- [google-maps](/questions/tagged/google-maps)
- [google-maps-api-3](/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-3)
- [google-maps-api-2](/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-2)

[google-maps-api-2](/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-2) concerns version 2 of the API, [which stops working May 19, 2013](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference).

As such, I perceive [google-maps](/questions/tagged/google-maps) to refer to Version 3 of the API by default. May we please merge [google-maps-api-3](/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-3) into [google-maps](/questions/tagged/google-maps)?

Comment: I'm all for renaming `google-maps` into `google-maps-api`!

Comment: @UnicornifiedBobby that's an even better idea

Comment: @UnicornifiedBobby Let's post that as a separate request.

Comment: Related (or possible duplicate?): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143846/google-maps-version-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I say no to this.  There are always questions that are version-specific to any API.

While questions with the version-agnostic tag are generally applicable to any version of the framework, and *may* assume features from the latest, if you have a question requires a *specific version*, then it should be tagged as such, *as well as* the version agnostic version.

Comment: OK, you win. Close?

Comment: @TinaCGHoehr It's not a game, I mean, there are no losers, and I'm just presenting an opinion.  If you want to see which way people go on this, I'm more than happy to leave it open.  But if you really want, we'll stamp this with a `status-declined`.

Comment: Let's leave the question open to stew for a while then